# iOS weird scale animation when Picture in Picture stops

Tags: ios, avkit, picture-in-picture

I'm working on Picture in Picture for a custom player, so I have to generate a `AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer` instance first to instantiate `AVPictureInPictureController`. I could not find a complete Apple demo for custom player, so I have no clue about my current weird animation: the player layer always does a scale animation before it completely stops.

In my code, I just set `canStartPictureInPictureAutomaticallyFromInline` to true in order to start Picture in Picture when switching to background. The only document I referred is https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/adopting_picture_in_picture_in_a_custom_player

I've tried many ways but none can remove this weird animation. [image]